# Is regularly viewing internet pornography unhealthy?

Tags: medical-science, psychology, pornography

Have there been any conclusive studies that found negative (or positive) effects from viewing internet pornography on a regular basis? Certainly a google search turns up a lot of results but most aren't scientific and relate to religion. I've heard claims about how no such company would sponsor such a study as it isn't profitable, or [studies](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/women/sex/6709646/All-men-watch-porn-scientists-find.html) have not had enough men who had never viewed porn to continue.

Here's an [article](http://www.dailydot.com/opinion/5-reasons-you-need-watch-porn/) claiming porn is not bad but actually healthy and it does site a few sources but certainly seems biased. Here's a [site](http://fightthenewdrug.org/) on the negative effects of porn consumption however, a lot of the sited facts don't directly relate to negative (or positive) effects or porn itself (for example just because the brain releases dopamine when viewing porn isn't a negative thing).

Comment: I've closed this as too broad, because there are too many elements involved in an answer to be satisfied here. There are questions of gender, frequency, types of porn, the confounding factors of the health effects of masturbation and climaxing. Any answer is likely to be complicated (e.g. what if it reduced the risk of prostate cancer but increased depression (invented claims)? What if it is correlated to being single which has its own health effects?) Let's find a narrow claim that can be independently investigated.

Comment: Here are some sources about porn and health that I found: http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/untp/i_am_a_published_psychologist_author_of_the/ , http://yourbrainonporn.com/research-articles-and-abstracts . Generally they mention erectile dysfunction, addiction and some other things, but I only glanced at them, so I have no idea how common are these effects. Happy reading.